# quantidade de elementos repetidos de um array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
compra = int(input('Valor da compra: R$'))
valorPago = int(input('Valor pago: R$'))
troco = valorPago - compra
dimDisponivel = [100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]
print(f'Troco: R${troco}\n')



for i in dimDisponivel:
    while troco >= i:
        print(f'{dimDisponivel.count(i)} de R${i}')
        troco -= i
```

Gostaria de saber como mostrar apenas uma vez a quantidade de determinada cédula repetida, pois se o programa detecta 3 notas de 2 reais, escreve 1 de cada por linha, e queria saber com colocar as 3 notas de 2 numa linha só.

Comment: Apesar das perguntas indicadas acima terem títulos que não parecem ter a ver com o seu caso, elas traram do mesmo problema. Basta adaptar as soluções para o seu caso

Answer (score 0):

O seu método count() está contando a quantidade de valores na lista, não as necessárias para completar o troco. Faça um contador dentro do while para isso.

```py
for i in dimDisponivel:
    count = 0
    while troco >= i:
        count += 1
        troco -= i
    if count != 0:
        print(f'{count} de R$ {i}')
```